# How to get sublist from left outter join table using linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-3.1

I have Users, Roles, and a UserRoles table. I'm trying to get a list of users with a sublist of all the roles they belong to.

I have the following query that's giving me issues when I try and populate a sublist. I am getting an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error when I attempt to use the `rolesGroup` IEnumerable. I've tried doing null checks but that throws another error saying `Null TypeMapping in Sql Tree`.

Any idea how I should be populating the `Roles` sublist?
Thanks!

```cs
                var q = from u in _dbContext.Users
                        join ur in _dbContext.UserRoles on u.Id equals ur.UserId
                        join r in _dbContext.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id  into rolesGroup
                        from rg in rolesGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new UserJS
                        {
                            Id = u.Id,
                            FirstName = u.FirstName,
                            LastName = u.LastName,
                            Roles = rolesGroup.Select(x => x .Name).ToList(), //<--- FAILING HERE
                        };
//DTO
    public class UserJS
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your query like this:

```
var q = from u in _dbContext.Users
                        join ur in _dbContext.UserRoles on u.Id equals ur.UserId
                        select new UserJS
                        {
                            Id = u.Id,
                            FirstName = u.FirstName,
                            LastName = u.LastName,
                            Roles =  _dbContext.Roles.Where(x=>x.Id == ur.RoleId).ToListAsync(), 
                        };
```

Comment: `rg` is not a collection so you can't use `rg.Select()`.

Comment: This runs but ```Roles``` does not get grouped. I get a new record for each user where Roles.Count() = 1.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using a sub query inside `select`.

```cs
                var q = from u in _dbContext.Users.Include(x => x.Doctor)
                        select new UserJS
                        {
                            Id = u.Id,
                            FirstName = u.FirstName,
                            LastName = u.LastName,
                            Roles = (from ur in _dbContext.UserRoles
                                     join r in _dbContext.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                                     where ur.UserId == u.Id
                                     orderby r.Name
                                     select r.Name).ToList(),
                        };
```